# php code to display datewise total in report

Tags: php

Updated code i post here with my changes...

plz suggest i am correct..with below code..

I changes and update your code with my php query and all..plz suggest there is need to change in below code....according to you..

And if i am wrong help me to correct this...

plz tell me where to put my php query.

**Earlier Code**

```
<?php   
$book = $database->getRows("SELECT DISTINCT bookingdate FROM receipt_entry");       
?>

<table border="1px solid #666" style="text-align:center;" cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>

    <tr>
    <th>Surveyor Name</th>
    <?php   foreach($book as $dt)   { ?>
    <td><?php echo $dt['bookingdate']; ?></td>  
    </tr>       
    <?php   
$book = $dt['bookingdate'];
$data = $database->getRows("select surveyor_name,bookingdate, count(DISTINCT receipt_no) As total from receipt_entry where bookingdate = '$book' group by surveyor_name,bookingdate");
?>
<?php   foreach($data as $db)   { ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $db['surveyor_name']; ?></td>        
    <td><?php echo $db['total']; ?></td>

    </tr>
<?php } }?>


    </table>



<table border=1>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Surveyor Name</th>
            <?php $book = $database->getRows("SELECT DISTINCT bookingdate FROM receipt_entry"); ?>
            <?php foreach($book as $date):?>
                <?php $dates[] = $date['bookingdate'];?>
                <th><?php echo $date['bookingdate'];?></th>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php $data = $database->getRows("select surveyor_name, count(DISTINCT receipt_no) As total,bookingdate from receipt_entry group by surveyor_name,bookingdate"); ?>
        <?php $j = 0;?> 
        <?php foreach($data as $key => $value):?>
            <?php $names[] = $value['surveyor_name'];?>
            <?php $uniValues = array_count_values($names);?>
            <?php if($uniValues[$value['surveyor_name']] == 1):?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $value['surveyor_name'];?>
                </td>
                <?php $i = 0;?>
                <?php foreach($book as $date):?>
                    <td align="center">
                        <?php if($names[$i] == $data[$j]['surveyor_name']):?>
                            <?php echo $data[$j]['total'];?>
                        <?php else:?>
                            <?php foreach($data as $dat):?>
                                <?php if($dat['surveyor_name'] == $names[$j] && $dates[$i] == $dat['bookingdate']):?>
                                    <?php echo $dat['total'];?>
                                <?php endif;?>
                            <?php endforeach;?>
                        <?php endif;?>
                    </td>
                    <?php ++$i;?>
                <?php endforeach;?>
            </tr>
            <?php endif;?>
            <?php ++$j;?>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

**Expected output**

```
     surveyor name  19-03-2015    20-03-2015   24-03-2015
      angel                                        1
      raj             2            
      sudnyesh                       1


   array
```

0 => 
    array
      'bookingdate' => string '19-03-2015' (length=10)
  1 => 
    array
      'bookingdate' => string '20-03-2015' (length=10)
  2 => 
    array
      'bookingdate' => string '24-03-2015' (length=10)
array
  0 => 
    array
      'surveyor_name' => string 'angel' (length=5)
      'total' => string '1' (length=1)
      'bookingdate' => string '24-03-2015' (length=10)
  1 => 
    array
      'surveyor_name' => string 'raj' (length=3)
      'total' => string '2' (length=1)
      'bookingdate' => string '19-03-2015' (length=10)
  2 => 
    array
      'surveyor_name' => string 'sudnyesh' (length=8)
      'total' => string '1' (length=1)
      'bookingdate' => string '20-03-2015' (length=10)

**Data Present in my database like below**

```
surveyor   bookingdate     receipt_no
 raj       19-03-2015        55
 raj       19-03-2015        55
 raj       19-03-2015        55
 raj       19-03-2015        55
 raj       19-03-2015        55
 raj       19-03-2015        55

 raj       19-03-2015        56
 raj       19-03-2015        56
 raj       19-03-2015        56
 raj       19-03-2015        56
 raj       19-03-2015        56
 raj       19-03-2015        56

sudnyesh    20-03-2015       700
sudnyesh    20-03-2015       700
sudnyesh    20-03-2015       700
sudnyesh    20-03-2015       700
sudnyesh    20-03-2015       700
sudnyesh    20-03-2015       700

angel       24-03-2015        702
angel       24-03-2015        702
angel       24-03-2015        702
angel       24-03-2015        702
angel       24-03-2015        702
angel       24-03-2015        702
```

Comment: Maybe could you learn about `foreach():` and `endforeach` syntax when dealing with HTML instead of using curly brackets. I'll have a deeper look at your code though.

Comment: Can we have the raw output from the query?

Comment: Nop, I meant the raw `array` you got from `$database->getRows('...');` not the HTML output.

Comment: Thanks but I meant the output of `var_dump($data);`.

Comment: I'd also need `var_dump($book);`

Comment: I cannot see how to do it without fetching `bookingdate` in your second query.

Comment: Almost there, but you would **need to fetch `bookingdate` in your second MySQL query**.

Comment: Just posted an answer, don't forget to add `bookingdate` in your second `SELECT` statement and you should be fine. Consider accepting the answer if it suits you and also, upvoting it to take in consideration the hour spent on your code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have your data fetched in that format (as per your question):

```
$book = array(
    array('bookingdate' => '20-03-2015'),
    array('bookingdate' => '21-03-2015'),
    array('bookingdate' => '22-03-2015'),
);

$data = array(
    array(
        'surveyor_name' => 'raj',
        'total' => '2',
        'bookingdate' => '20-03-2015'
    ),
    array(
        'surveyor_name' => 'angel',
        'total' => '1',
        'bookingdate' => '21-03-2015'
    ),
    array(
        'surveyor_name' => 'raj',
        'total' => '1',
        'bookingdate' => '22-03-2015'
    ),
);
```

Then, you can construct your HTML `table` like so:

```
<?php $book = $database->getRows("SELECT DISTINCT bookingdate FROM receipt_entry"); ?>
<?php $data = $database->getRows("select surveyor_name, count(DISTINCT receipt_no) As total,bookingdate from receipt_entry group by surveyor_name,bookingdate"); ?>
<table border="1px solid #666" style="text-align:center;" cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Surveyor Name</th>
        <?php foreach($book as $date):?>
            <?php $dates[] = $date['bookingdate'];?>
            <th><?php echo $date['bookingdate'];?></th>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php $j = 0;?>
    <?php foreach($data as $key => $value):?>
        <?php $names[] = $value['surveyor_name'];?>
        <?php $uniValues = array_count_values($names);?>
        <?php if($uniValues[$value['surveyor_name']] == 1):?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo $value['surveyor_name'];?>
            </td>
            <?php $i = 0;?>
            <?php foreach($book as $date):?>
                <td align="center">
                    <?php if($names[$i] == $data[$j]['surveyor_name']):?>
                        <?php echo $data[$j]['total'];?>
                    <?php else:?>
                        <?php foreach($data as $dat):?>
                            <?php if($dat['surveyor_name'] == $names[$j] && $dates[$i] == $dat['bookingdate']):?>
                                <?php echo $dat['total'];?>
                            <?php endif;?>
                        <?php endforeach;?>
                    <?php endif;?>
                </td>
                <?php ++$i;?>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </tr>
        <?php endif;?>
        <?php ++$j;?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And have your data displayed as such:

[image]

Comment: Why did you edited your question? This won't get any others users to help you. Anyway, you should retrieve your data as per the `array`s I've posted at the beginning of the answer. You need to have both `$book` and `$data` set up with proper data.

Comment: Please consider upvoting my answer then. You need to put your fetched data with your MySQL queries into `$book` and `$data` **as you did at the very first time**.

Comment: Thanks, please consider also upvoting it as well. The query you'd need to run for the table to be displayed nicely are the **exact** ones you posted earlier before editing the question. Please put them back.

Comment: Just edited the answer with both queries to add in order for it to work.

Comment: Ok so, please, I'm begging you, can you **please** post the **exact** output of `var_dump($book)` and `var_dump($data)`. This is the last time I'm asking.

Comment: I am sorry but this is not proper PHP array formatting. You are not able to properly copy/paste code, how can I help you on this one?

Comment: **AGAIN**, you have **not** copied/pasted the output of `var_dump($book)` and `var_dump($data)`. I'm sorry but I'm starting loosing patience here. How do you want people to help you if you're not able to provide them with what they've been asking for hours??

Comment: hello sir,can you help me on this question...how to display sum of both horizontal and vertical coulmns