# php code to display datewise count in pivot rows

Tags: php

Data Present in my database like below...

columnname 
surveyor_name -varchar

bookingdate - varchar

receipt_no - varchar

```
surveyor   bookingdate     receipt_no

 raj       19-03-2015        55
 raj       19-03-2015        55
 raj       19-03-2015        55
 raj       19-03-2015        55
 raj       19-03-2015        55
 raj       19-03-2015        55

 raj       19-03-2015        56
 raj       19-03-2015        56
 raj       19-03-2015        56
 raj       19-03-2015        56
 raj       19-03-2015        56
 raj       19-03-2015        56

sudnyesh    20-03-2015       700
sudnyesh    20-03-2015       700
sudnyesh    20-03-2015       700
sudnyesh    20-03-2015       700
sudnyesh    20-03-2015       700
sudnyesh    20-03-2015       700

angel       24-03-2015        702
angel       24-03-2015        702
angel       24-03-2015        702
angel       24-03-2015        702
angel       24-03-2015        702
angel       24-03-2015        702
```

**Expected output**

```
 surveyor name  19-03-2015    20-03-2015   24-03-2015
  angel                                        1
  raj             2            
  sudnyesh                       1
```

**But my code display output like below...**

```
surveyor name  19-03-2015    20-03-2015   24-03-2015
  angel            1                            1
  raj             2             2
  sudnyesh                       1              1
```

Can anyone help me to display proper output as i want.

below is my code.

**FOR EX - In my expected output....**

raj has create 2 receipt 55,56 on 19-03-2015 hence we display total 2 in front of raj below 19-03-2015

sudnyesh has create 1 receipt 700 on 20-03-2015 hence we display total 1 in front of sudnyesh below 20-03-2015 etc...

plz help me to achieve this..

```
<?php $book = $database->getRows("SELECT DISTINCT bookingdate FROM receipt_entry"); ?>
<?php $data = $database->getRows("select surveyor_name, count(DISTINCT receipt_no) As total,bookingdate from receipt_entry group by surveyor_name,bookingdate");  ?>
<table border="1px solid #666" style="text-align:center;" cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Surveyor Name</th>
        <?php foreach($book as $date):?>
            <?php $dates[] = $date['bookingdate'];?>
            <th><?php echo $date['bookingdate'];?></th>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php $j = 0;?>
    <?php foreach($data as $key => $value):?>
        <?php $names[] = $value['surveyor_name'];?>
        <?php $uniValues = array_count_values($names);?>
        <?php if($uniValues[$value['surveyor_name']] == 1):?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo $value['surveyor_name'];?>
            </td>
            <?php $i = 0;?>
            <?php foreach($book as $date):?>
                <td align="center">
                    <?php if($names[$i] == $data[$j]['surveyor_name']):?>
                        <?php echo $data[$j]['total'];?>
                    <?php else:?>
                        <?php foreach($data as $dat):?>
                            <?php if($dat['surveyor_name'] == $names[$j] && $dates[$i] == $dat['bookingdate']):?>
                                <?php echo $dat['total'];?>
                            <?php endif;?>
                        <?php endforeach;?>
                    <?php endif;?>
                </td>
                <?php ++$i;?>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </tr>
        <?php endif;?>
        <?php ++$j;?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Varsha, I already gave you an answer on this question. Do you have your arrays formatted properly as per the requirements on my answer?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/29282535/2788131

Comment: possible duplicate of [php code to display datewise total in report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29280267/php-code-to-display-datewise-total-in-report)